# My form is not updating when its. preloaded with default value - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have these input fields I want to already show default values in, but i also want to be able to update those values

here is the code- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vfcqkh?file=src/App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';
export default function App() {
  const baseData = [
    {nutrient: 'Energy',per100: '449kcal', per35: '157kcal', "id": 6 },
    {nutrient: 'Fat',per100: '24.4g', per35: '8.6g', "id": 1 },
    { nutrient: 'Saturated fat',per100: '4.5g', per35: '1.6g', "id": 2 },
    { nutrient: 'Monounsaturated fat',per100: '13.6g', per35: '4.8g', "id": 3 }
  ];
  // set original state as your data
  const [data, setData] = useState(baseData);
  const updateValue = e => {
    const copiedData = [...data]; //to avoid mutating state
    let index = copiedData.findIndex(obj => obj.id == e.target.id);
    copiedData[index].nutrient = e.target.value;
    setData(copiedData);
  };
  return (
    <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        { Object.keys(baseData[0]).map(({id,nutrient}) => (
          <input type="text"   key={id}  id={id}  value={nutrient} name="productName" onChange={(e) => updateValue(e)} />
        ))}
      </div>
      {baseData.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          {Object.values(item).map(({id,nutrient}) => (
            <input type="text" key={id} id={id}  value={nutrient} id="name" name="productName" onChange={(e) => updateValue(e)} />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to display the initial values of the form then while the user is typing or typed in values the value in the `<input type="text" name="name"/>` will be update or do you want to update the state with the value typed in the input field?

### Displaying Default values

change the value prop/attribute of the input to defaultValue

```js
 <input type="text"   key={id}  id={id}  defaultValue={nutrient} name="productName" onChange={(e) => updateValue(e)} />
```

This way user can type in value and the initial values will also be displayed.

### Update values

in you update function, you can access the value that the user typed by doing this:

```js
updateValue(e){

  let value= e.target.value

// then do state update here

}
```

### Re-defined Solution

This should work properly as I have tested the code and run it successfully

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const baseData = [
    { nutrient: "Energy", per100: "449kcal", per35: "157kcal", id: 6 },
    { nutrient: "Fat", per100: "24.4g", per35: "8.6g", id: 1 },
    { nutrient: "Saturated fat", per100: "4.5g", per35: "1.6g", id: 2 },
    { nutrient: "Monounsaturated fat", per100: "13.6g", per35: "4.8g", id: 3 },
  ];

  // set original state as your data
  const [data, setData] = useState(baseData);
  const updateValue = (e) => {
    const copiedData = [...data]; //to avoid mutating state
    let index = copiedData.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === e.target.id);
    copiedData[index].nutrient = e.target.value;
    setData(copiedData);
  };

  // initialize vars to hold the baseData object keys and vals
  let baseDataKeys = [],
    baseDataVals = [];

  // first get all the keys of the objects and store them in this var
  baseData.forEach((keys) => {
    baseDataKeys = Object.keys(keys);
  });
  // debug to see the keys
  console.log(baseDataKeys);

  // Secondly get all the values of the objects and store then in this var
  baseData.forEach((vals) => {
    baseDataVals = Object.values(vals);
  });
  // debug to see the valus
  console.log(baseDataVals);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          {baseDataKeys.map((keys) => (
            <input
              type="text"
              key={keys}
              id={keys}
              defaultValue={keys}
              name="productName"
              onChange={(e) => updateValue(e)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        {/* This is for the values */}
        {baseDataVals.map((vals) => (
          <div key={vals}>
            <input
              type="text"
              id={vals}
              defaultValue={vals}
              id="name"
              name="productName"
              onChange={(e) => updateValue(e)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try this updated solution this is going to work accurately

Comment: so then i can just do setData(value) ?

Comment: the intputs are still empty bro

Comment: have you changed the value='...' to defaultValue='....'?

Comment: The real values to display are in id `param` in the `map(id, nutrient)`. If i may ask which values from the array of objects above do you want to show as default values?

Comment: I want all the values and keys to be shown as default value

Comment: Check out the updated solution and implement it it's going to work now.

Comment: Don't forget to check this answer if your problem is resolved!